# Nvidia GPU supprt in 19.10

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I installed the new 19.10 version as i understand its already includes Nvidia drivers?
i try to do offline installation (no internet) but after reboot there was no option to choose Nvidia propriety driver.

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This will show You what driver is being used for the display: `sudo lshw -C display | grep -i driver`.